# How to retrieve user phone number in Action for the Assistant

Tags: dialogflow-es, actions-on-google

How do i get the phone number of a user, who uses my Dialogflow?

I see email, name and so on in [these docs](https://actions-on-google.github.io/actions-on-google-nodejs/classes/conversation.user.html), but I don't see phone number. Is it even possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may need to capture it from the user itself by creating a parameter/entity. Once captured, validate it via webhook if needed for the number of digits.

This is how I am doing:

[image]

Comment: Yes, to add on to what Abhinav said, there is no easy-to-use call to get the user's phone number.